# Practical difference between .pls and .sql file in oracle

Tags: oracle, unix, sqlplus, ksh

What is the practical difference between .pls and .sql file in oracle. 
What are the restrictions on different types of statements in both?

I am given a project in unix(korn script) which uses both .sql and .pls files in different places. Trying to figure out which should be used where.

Comment: I remember the days of having various files scattered around with code in -- not backed up, not validatable without executing it. You should do yourself a favour and migrate all of that code to packed procedures in the database, using DBMS_Scheduler for any scheduling requirements

Answer (score 8, accepted):

File suffixes are to a large extent just a matter of convention.  We can use them to provide useful metadata to other developers.

So `.pls` indicates (we hope) that the file is a PL/SQL script, creating a PL/SQL package or stored procedure.  In other shops we might see `.pks` and `.pkb` to indicate a package spec script and a package body script respectively.  A file with a `.tab` or a `.tbl` extension indicates DDL to create a table.  Because this is just a convention it requires discipline (or code reviews) to make sure we remain consistent.

The one difference is `.sql`.  Although the convention is that it represents some SQL (a query, or perhaps DML or DDL) it has a special property in SQL*Plus.  If we have a script called `whatever.sql` we can call it like this  in SQL*Plus...

```
SQL>  @whatever
```

... whereas if a script has any other extension we must include the extension in the call...

```
SQL>  @whatever.pls
```

Other IDEs or others clients (e.g. build scripts) may use file extensions as a filtering mechanisms or for applying syntax highlighting, but their rules should always be controlled by preferences.

> " What are the restrictions on different types of statements in both?"

To sum up, there are no restrictions.  Some places I have worked used nothing but `.sql` files,  Others had a complicated menagerie of scripts: `.tbl`, `.idx`, `.vw`, etc.  Sociopaths can use just `.txt` for all their files: the database won't care.  Provided it's valid Oracle syntax the code will run.

Comment: So in sqlplus ,irrespective of the extension we can have pl/sql statements like declaration , cursors etc.. is it right? or in other words even if i change .pls to .sql it will still work?

Comment: It will run yes.  You probably shouldn't change extensionst.  It would be better to ask your co-workers what conventions they use and adhere to those.

Comment: It's worth noting that the '.sql' extension will always be used in the case where you have scripts with a .sql extension and no extension at all (This scenarios should never really happen) .   SQL> ! cat full
select 'full' from dual;

SQL> ! cat full.sql
select 'sql' from dual;

SQL> @full

'SQ
---
sql

Comment: Good answer. Because we are on Windows, a convention our team uses is .pls for Oracle PL-SQL files, and .sql for Microsoft SQL Server T-SQL files. That way the default file associations mean the files always open in the correct program.